# Is there a way to get rid of #N/A error in CubeValue Formula when using a date range and a particular date isn't available in that range?

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I'm using CubeValue formula to fetch "Volume" data from Power Pivot Data Model, however returning #N/A error because few of dates aren't available within the range specified.

If I'm giving range from 1st Mar to 31st Mar and if 1 of the date (example 20th March) is missing in that range in model, then this function returns error. How do I sort this issue?

Here is the formula:

```
=CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Measures].[Sum of Volume]",CUBESET("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[volume_of_tobi].[Date].&["&B3&"]:[volume_of_tobi].[Date].&["&B4&"]"))
```

Cell Reference B3 and B4 is Date range (Start date and End date)

Comment: you can always wrap it in `=Iferror()` and put the desired outcome when errors exist.

Comment: let us say  I'm giving a range from 1st mar to 3rd mar (3 days) and the data is available for 1st and 3rd only (2nd data is not available), then this formula returns error. But I"d like the sum of 1st and 3rd pls.